# Quickly remove first n lines from many text files

Tags: python, file-io, sed, performance

I need to create an output text file by deleting the first two lines of the input file.

At the moment I'm using
sed "1,2d" input.txt > output.txt

I need to do this for thousands of files, so am using python:

```
import os
for filename in somelist:
  os.system('sed "1,2d" %s-in.txt > %s-out.txt'%(filename,filename))
```

but this is quite slow.

I need to keep the original file, so I can't sed in place.

Is there a way to do this faster? Using something other than sed?Perhaps using some other scripting language than python? Is it worth writing a short C program, or is the file-writing disk-access likely to be the bottleneck?

Comment: One issue with using os.system() is that it spawns a new shell every loop which adds a bit of overhead. Running directly in a loop in e.g. bash would reduce the overhead a little bit (but the performance increase would probably only be theoretical, since disk I/O is the limiting factor as mentioned by others)

Comment: @pafcu: It might not be so theoretical if the files were all four lines. But you could get pretty much the same improvement by using `exec` instead of `system`, I'd imagine. Don't really need a shell for this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `tail`. Doubt anything could be significantly faster:

```
tail -n +3 input.txt > output.txt
```

Wrap it in your loop of choice. But I really doubt sed is a whole ton slower - as you say, disk i/o is usually the ultimate bottleneck.

Comment: Thanks, I've just tried and it's essentially indistinguishable from the original in how long it takes to run (just like ghostdog's sed -i.bak), so I suspect it's an i/o bottleneck.

Comment: I know there's no way I'll get an answer but... why'd this get downvoted? It's *the* canonical way to do this operation in *nix.

Answer (score 4):

I think this will be faster than launching sed:

```
import os
import shutil

path = '/some/path/to/files/'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    basename, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
    newname = os.path.join(path, basename + '-out' + ext)
    with open(fullname) as read:
        #skip first two lines
        for n in xrange(2):
            read.readline()
        # hand the rest to shutil.copyfileobj
        with open(newname, 'w') as write:
            shutil.copyfileobj(read, write)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for file in *.ext
do
    sed -i.bak -n '3,$p' $file 
done
```

or just

```
sed -i.bak -n '3,$p' *.ext
```

Comment: That's very nice, thanks, but unfortunately it appears that i/o is the bottleneck.